# production site routes to staging site after cloning

Tags: redirect, directory, staging, production

Hello I am new to wordpress, our website was down (due to plugin update) I was not even able to access the admin panel due to this, so I went to the directory and copied from our staging directory (the only working directory) to the public_html directory (Production Directory).
This did fix access to the website but now when I access the website the home page is referencing the correct directory (non staging) but when I navigate to any tabs I am re-routed to the staging site (staging directory) which I do not want.
Does anyone know how to fix this in order to stop the public html from redirecting to the staging html?

Comment: If you copied over all the files from staging's `public_html` then that means you also copied over the `wp-config.php` file.  That files tells WordPress which database to use. So when you first load the site, it's loading WP because that's what's in the root directory (`public_html`).  You have to either get the `wp-config.php` from a back-up of the live site and replace that, or you have to edit the file so that it connects to the right database:  https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/
Next time, only copy over the `wp-content` folder.

Comment: Thank you very much, this did seem to be the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Check your production site's `wp-config.php` file for one or both of these lines:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com' );
```

...and set them as appropriate if they exist.

These constants will override the settings in the database if they're present. See [Editing `wp-config.php`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/) for details.